# Angular 11 DI - AuthService is not defined

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm struggling with the Angular Dependency Injection lifecycle..

I keep getting the below error

[image]

Login Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import AuthService from '@app/core/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent {

  public loading = true;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  login() {
    this.authService.login();
  }
}
```

AuthService.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export default class AuthService {
  login() { }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  ....
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Shouldn't the `providedIn: 'root'` make it available for the whole application?
I also tried making it part of the providers: [] in app.module.ts to no avail.
Issue also seems to be intermittent, sometimes it works.

Comment: Try import Authservice with brackets `import { AuthService} from '@app/core/services/auth.service';`

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue, but since it is intermittent, I'll give it a few more tries and let you know.. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm curious, why would leaving off the curly braces fail intermittently?

Comment: @BlackICE that's what I'm trying to figure out, doesn't make any sense to me either. But after I put them it stopped failing. At least for now.